# Amazon API - MaxAggregateShipQuantity Vs MaxOrderQuantity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-marketplace

Can someone tell me the difference between these two elements used in a product listing feed?

```
<xsd:element name="MaxAggregateShipQuantity" type="xsd:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
```

and

```
<xsd:element name="MaxOrderQuantity" type="xsd:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0"/>
```

[From here](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=320438),  `MaxAggrgateShipQuantity` allocates a maximum number of products available on any one order, but how does this differ from `MaxOrderQuantity`?

[XSD Document](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/Product.xsd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MaxAggrgateShipQuantity`  - This will say how any items are including in the shipping cost. If shipping is £5 and the MaxAggrgateShipQuantity flag is set to two then a customer who purchased four products would be charge £10 delivery.

`MaxOrderQuantity` - Maximum product quantity a customer can order at any one time.